# GCC/XCode equivalent of _CrtCheckMemory?

Tags: c++, xcode, debugging, heap-memory

When dealing with random memory overwrites, in MSVC it is possible to validate the state of the heap at various points with a call to _CrtCheckMemory, and know with at least a small level of confidence that the code up until the check was not responsible for any errors that might cause new or malloc to fail later.

In XCode, whats the equivalent way to try and box in a memory overwrite? All I have at the moment is a random failure of a call to new, somewhere deep in the bowels of some code with no real idea of how long the code has been running with a corrupt heap up until that point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This feature IS actually built into the heap in GCC.
As described [here](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/Performance/Conceptual/ManagingMemory/Articles/MallocDebug.html)
The easiest way to enable it is on the XCode::Run menu: `Enable Guard Malloc`

Answer (score 0):

As it is only implied in Neil's answer, lets make this explicit:

As far as I know there isn't any tool that is as readily available as _CrtCheckMemory for gcc. 
IIRC there are some checked malloc libraries out there, but I didn't find them as usable as _CrtCheckMemory. 
There is however [Valgrind](http://valgrind.org/) which is deployed unintrusively, and gives 
you a much more throughout result.

Answer (score -1):

This doesn't address your question directly, but I felt compelled to respond. As you say, tools like the CRT check functions only give you a small level of confidence, and don't address resource leaks other than memory. If you find yourself depending on such tools I would say there is something very, very wrong with your approach to C++ development. In the past 10 years, I have not had a single problem in my code associated with memory leakage. This is not because I am some C++ coding god, but because I use the basic tools of RAII, smart pointers and standard library collections in my code, and wherever possible avoid explicit dynamic memory allocation using `new`. Whenever you find yourself writing a line of code like:

```
Something * p = new Something;
```

stop, and ask yourself "Is there some way I could avoid doing this?" and if the answer is "no", then ask yourself why you are allocating memory to a raw pointer, and if you can't find any way around that (which should very rarely be the case, immediately write the code to manage the pointers de-allocation, and make sure that that code is exception-safe.

If you take this approach, you won't need tools like special CRT functions or Valgrind, and you will save yourself oceans of time in debugging.

Comment: In an ideal world it would be possible to be a pure c++ programmer where all the structures in the program were implementable with c++ idioms.
In my world I am porting a 10 year old windows codebase to the Mac,thats written in... well. a mix of C, C+ (a weird subset of C++ produced by people who learnt C++ after C and write what is essentially C code, but with some classes), C++ that all has to interoperate with dynamic libraries lls that export functionality by exporting C functions, C functions making interfaces, or just by exporting c++ classes. fun.

Comment: This is a ridiculous statement. I was a developer at Microsoft and _CrtCheckMemory() is used quite extensively. Based on this persons statement I guess we did everything wrong at Microsoft. 

Verifying the integrity of the heap and stack is helpful to find buffer overruns, pointer assignment issues, bugs that the compiler generates, ...
Use Valgrind on linux or roll your own tool that hooks allocations and performs your own check with some kind of magic number of the beginning and end of the allocation.